# Delay between animations on a UIImageView in iOS

Tags: ios, animation, ios5

I have an animation which is made up of an array of images, on which I then run

```
[myUIImageView startAnimating]
```

**I want the animation to run once, then stop for 3 seconds, then repeat.**

I need to run this animation in a separate thread so I have

```
NSThread *animationThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startAnimTask) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; 
[animationThread start];
```

in my viewDidLoad, and then

```
-(void) startAnimTask {

   //create array of images here; animationDuration (3) and animationRepeatCount (1)
   [self setUpAnimation];

   while (true){
       [myUIImageView startAnimating];
       usleep(3);        
       [myUIImageView stopAnimating];
       usleep(3);    
   }
}
```

Using this method, I receive a memory warning. I've also tried running the start and stop on the MainThread with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this:

```
 [myUIImageView startAnimating];
 [self performSelector:@selector(startAnimTask) 
         withObject:nil 
         afterDelay:(myUIImageView.animationDuration+3.0)];
```

Now selector is:

```
 -(void)startAnimTask
 {
   [myUIImageView startAnimating];
   //repeat again then add above selector code line here
 }
```

Comment: Should this not be performSelectorOnMainThread? It doesn't seem to work with just performSelector

Comment: what //repeat again then refer for?

Answer (score 1):

UI is not thread safe, so UI calls should be executed only in main thread, maybe this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can go with this:

```
  [self performSelector:@selector(startAnimTask) 
             withObject:nil 
             afterDelay:0.1];

  [self performSelector:@selector(startAnimTask) 
             withObject:nil 
             afterDelay:3.0];
```

In *startAnimTask* method write your animation logic code.

Enjoy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach to complete your task:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myTask) 
             withObject:nil 
             afterDelay:3.0];

-(void)myTask{

//Write your logic for animation

}
```

Comment: that's what i said u have anything differnet